# Visualize a dependency graph of packages for a cabal project?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

There is `ghc-pkg dot` but that seems to only work for a ghc package database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`cabal-plan`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-plan) executable to generate a dependency graph. First install `cabal-plan` with:

```bash
cabal install cabal-plan
```

Then you can go to your cabal package directory and run:

```bash
cabal-plan dot | dot -Tpdf -odeps.pdf
```

(You have to run `cabal build` or `cabal configure` first if you have not done so already)

This will produce a dependency graph in PDF form in the file `deps.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much answers it!

Do you know if there is a way to filter out packages by pattern? There is the `--root` flag but that starts the graph from some root, but I'd like to have a pattern to exclude or include packages entirely.

Comment: No, I wouldn't know how to do that. But perhaps there are general tools for filtering out nodes from the intermediate graphviz dot file?

Comment: FWIW, I had to use the `-fexe` flag to get the executable to install. By default `cabal install cabal-plan` didn't install the executable for me.

Comment: @sjakobi the Hackage page lists the exe option as enabled by default, so it is strange that you had to enable it manually.

Comment: Yeah. It's an automatic flag though, so it seems that Cabal's solver decided to disable it in my case.

Comment: Regarding the pruning of the dependency graph, I think that can be achieved by piping the `cabal-plan dot` output through `grep`, e.g. `cabal-plan dot | grep -vE '"(base|ghc-prim|template-haskell)-[0-9]'`.

Comment: This seems to prune most of the boot libraries: `cabal-plan dot | grep -vE '"(Cabal|Win32|array|base|binary|bytestring|containers|deepseq|directory|exceptions|filepath|ghc-bignum|ghc-prim|haskeline|hpc|integer-gmp|libiserv|mtl|parsec|pretty|process|rts|stm|template-haskell|terminfo|text|time|transformers|unix|xhtml)-[0-9]'`

Comment: For me, the executable installed by default. Perhaps @sjakobi you have it overridden in a cabal config file somewhere?